# Como fazer um caminho de um ponto a outro ponto em um grafo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou  tentando modificar o seguinte algoritmo (O busca em Largura) para iniciar um ponto e identificar um caminho até outro ponto especificado.

```
def buscaLargura(grafo, inicial):
    visitados = []
    fila = [inicial]
    while len(fila) > 0:  # Enquanto a fila nao estiver
        vertice = fila.pop(0)
        if vertice not in visitados:
            visitados.append(vertice)
            fila.extend(grafo[vertice])
    return visitados
```

Exemplo: Quero chegar do ponto 5 até o ponto 6 e retornar esse caminho...
[image]

Utilizei a biblioteca networkx para fazer o grafo, alguém tem alguma dica para do que eu possa fazer para realizar tal função ?